# How does a local merge differ from a merge on Github?

Tags: git, github, merge

When merging a branch into the master branch, the section "network", in "insight" gave me a view of the branch I just merged into the master branch:

[Branch merge into master: from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqmVS.png)

However, when doing so locally, in the shell, it seems like everything works fine but int the insight, the merged branch disappears:

[Branch merge into master: from shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah4t6.png)

These are the steps I followed in order to have this result:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin (url)
$ touch README.md
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "1"
$ git push -u origin master
$ git checkout -b branch1
$ touch 2.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "2"
$ git push origin branch1
$ git checkout master
$ git merge branch1
$ git push
```

Is it equal to a merge from Github, which would mean that Github's insight is a bit bugged? Or is there a difference between a local merge (like the one I did) and a merge done from Github? What is going on?

Comment: You're doing a FF-merge locally.

Comment: Doesn't the `push` that follows the local merge make this merge on Github? And anyway, why did the branch created disappear in the insight?

Comment: No, `push` sends commits to the other Git on GitHub, then requests (politely or forcefully depending on your `git push` command) that they change their branch name pointers to match what you suggest/command. No merging happens at this point, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [tkausl commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591380/how-does-a-local-merge-differ-from-a-merge-on-github#comment82139805_47591380), you ran `git merge branch1`.  This permits `git merge` to do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge operation if that's possible, and here, it *is* possible.

The "merge" clicky button on GitHub defaults to doing the equivalent of `git merge --no-ff`,<sup>1</sup> which prevents `git merge` from doing a fast-forward operation.  Were the fast-forward operation not possible, the `--no-ff` would have no effect, so you would not have seen a different result.

If you want to avoid fast-forward merging locally, use `--no-ff`.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, it seems to default to whatever you did last time, but initially that's the equivalent of `git merge --no-ff`: just merge, not GitHub's rebase-and-merge, and not GitHub's squash-and-merge.